# OrientBaseGraph's getVertices(String arg0, String[] arg1, Object[] arg2) doesn't return subclasses

Tags: orientdb, tinkerpop-blueprint

I am using orientdb 2.1.4. I have a class(Vertex) ParentV which has subclass(Vertex) ChildV.

When I query the database using getVertices("ParentV", new String[]{key}, new Object[]{value}), no results of "ChildV" type are found.

Could anyone let me know how to enable polymorphic search in above function because I need all the results(including parent and child classes) where given key matches given value.

**Note:** I can't use any other getVertices function because there are cases with multiple key and values. These functions are provided by tinkerpop blueprints APIs.

Comment: Looking the signature of the method getVertices,
I think that you can use g.getVertices("ParentV",true) 
and after you can filter on the key

Comment: Thanks Alessandro. But that would make the search slow if number of records are huge and only one record matches the key.

Comment: You are right.
Alternatively, you can combine the results of the following instructions
1) g.getVertices("ParentV", key,object);
2) g.getVertices("ChildV",  key,object);